# Over the memory limit when changing Magento template

Tags: magento, nginx, magento-1.7, php

I'm trying to run Magento community edition 1.7.0.2

using NGINX, PHP FPM

on 512Mb RAM VPS, Ubuntu 12.04.3 32Bit.

Whenever I try to change the default template by changing all the settings under

System->Configuration->Design->Themes by setting all of options, i.e.

Templates, Skin (Images / CSS), Layout, Default

to provided *modern* template (as well as other template) I get over the PHP memory limit.

Even if I set the limit to 256Mb.

I find it strange, because I was able to make it on shared hosting with less RAM, but on Apache, I guess.

Each time I attempt this - it fails and it is impossible to get either to admin or front end - getting white screen. I solve it by restoring machine from the snapshot.

Can anyone help me debug this?

Update:

Actually, I'm not even able to refresh configuration cache. One of the php-fpm processes increases memory use until it reaches max ram...

> 2014/01/06 16:58:09 [error] 892#0: 
>   *27 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:   Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes)
>   in 
>   /usr/share/nginx/www/spaparts/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
>   on line 622"
>
> while reading response header from upstream, client: 66.249.66.xxx,
>   server: domain.com,
>
> request: "GET /index.php/apparel/shoes.html?cat=16 HTTP/1.1",
>
> upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com"

Comment: check error logs for the errors.`var/log`.

Comment: Getting white screen error is something related to PHP exception. You can check app/Mage.php and debug where its halts and throws exception.

Comment: Anemic system for running Magento. With 512Mb, where's the web server, the OS and MySQL going to run when you start using Magento with more than 3 users? 1.7.0.2 requires a bare minimum of 256M for PHP memory_limit.

Comment: Mahmood, the errors are about running out of memory:
http://pastebin.com/JqhmW2DH
Those seem to be not in specific place. The more memory I allocate - the later it fails in different line, I suspect.
I even tried to make SWAP file and set PHP memory limit to 512. It fails then on 502 - bad gateway, and based on what I saw PHP process fails causing this error.

Comment: Fiasco, I agree that with time, it might require more memory and CPU, and the hosting allows to run the same machine on more powerful machine if needed. But I suspect this is not the problem here. 

I'm able to change the themes without any problem on the shared hosting, where it has 90M as memory_limit.

Comment: I allocate 512MB per each request... Beef up the ram and retry. The error says that the configured amount of ram (256MB) has been fully used and magento is trying to allocate another 32 bytes but you don't have it left as you have used it all already. You simply need to increase it or optimize your product listing blocks. Seriously though, you need a serious amount of memory to run a live magento installation and a moderate amount for development. Use the profiler to see where the memory is being used and by what blocks and maybe the code can be optimised, but easier to increase ram.

Comment: I suspect you are using file cache. Instead of using the admin to clear it, remove `var/cache` entirely. If this does not fix it, you will need to go through values in the core_config_data table and try to figure out, where you might be generating a loop.

Comment: @Melvyn - I used to have xCache running and enabled in Magento. 
Then I though, maybe xCache is consuming too much RAM and disabled it in Magento and overall. 
So, I guess I ue file cache now, but there are no Magento files in the var/cache as far as I can see.
And I did delete var/cache at some point while trying to troubleshoot it without any changes.
But your hint about the loop in the config was right on the money!!!

I have setup the {{secure_base_url}} and {{unsecure_base_url}} to have the same reference instead of real url, and it was causing all the trouble!!! Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I though it would be nice to write the details, in case anyone else is having similar trouble.

So, the over the limit memory PHP errors were caused by the: 
{{unsecure_base_url}} being set to "{{unsecure_base_url}}"
{{secure_base_url}} being set to "{{secure_base_url}}"

This was suggested somewhere as the way to allow the change the domain of the magento install, and it allows to run it as usual, but seems to cause some loops and over the limit RAM consumption.

After changing the settings in System->Configuration->Web everything is back to normal, I was able to clear cache, change theme etc.

Thanks everyone for all your suggestions!